# Picker inside alert window in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, alert, picker

I am trying to get two pickers inside an alert window. One to selct a user and the second to select the date.
But none of the pickers is displayed. the textfields are displayed and are working fine.
If I place those same pickers outside of the alert they work fine as well.
I am very new to SwiftUI and don't know where the problem lies. I guess it has something to do with the size of the alert window, but not sure how to fix it.
Any help is much appreciated.

This is the code so far:

```
struct ProjectsView: View {

@State private var date = Date()
@State private var project = ""
@State private var user = ""
let userList = [“Tom”, “Anna”, “Mike”]
}

var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
                
                VStack {
                    createBtn
                    
                }
                
            }
}

private extension ProjectsView {
    
    var createBtn: some View {
        Button(action: showAlert){
            Text("Add project")
        }
        .alert("Add project", isPresented: $showingMessage) {
            TextField("Project", text: $project)
            Picker(selection: $user, label: Text(“User”)) {
                ForEach(userList, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
            
            DatePicker(“Date”, selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            Button(“Save”, action: saveProject)
            Button(“Cancel”, role: .cancel) {}
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to be more appropriate to use a `.sheet(...)` for this.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, thank you very much for the reply. I will try .sheet, did not get around to implementing this yet.

Comment: It's very simple, just use `.sheet(isPresented: $showingMessage) {...}` instead of your `.alert(...)`